# Is there a way to export my Facebook status'?

Tags: facebook, export

I need a text document of my facebook status updates for all time. What's the quickest way to do this?

Comment: I could tell you the quickest way if you joined in 2008 and later.

Comment: I could write you a simple python script to get all your messages if you offer 500 bounty :P

Comment: Sorry... probably not worth the bounty...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Login to your Facebook
2. Go to: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user
3. Click on the `statuses` from the `Connections` table
4. Replace the default `arjun` username with yours or just `me` in the `URL`
5. Go to [Online JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) and Paste the result of the previous page there
6. Click on the `Viewer` Tab
7. Have fun with your status messages :)

It displays only the last 25 status updates but you can get the next 25 if you'll follow the last entry of the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) entry. I'm not going into more details because we are not on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there seems to be some discontinuity in Facebook Storage

As shown by this Facebook application

http://apps.facebook.com/mystatuses

This retrieves all status updates since 2008 in a nice format

> Phwd Double Click Insert Coin for Two
>   Player in Google Pacman (Fri, 21 May
>   2010 17:37:58 GMT)

I tried to do it on my own using the Facebook Test Console

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/

and the `graph/me/statuses` call. I got the same result (only since 2008).

Honestly I tried just clicking Older Posts and that seems to be the best way. Unless you joined in 2005 and earlier and push 100 updates a day there is no way it will take long.

There is another way but it seems only a handful of users have the feature

google query `site:http://www.facebook.com/feeds/ inurl:status`

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [Facebook's API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api), but that would require some programming. I've been searching for an easier solution but nothing yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Backupify](http://backupify.com) will backup your facebook account (among many other service) and give you one single xml file with all your updates in which you can download and do what you like with.

Comment: looks promising :D

Answer (score 1):

[Archive-fb.com](http://archive-fb.com) lets you do exactly this.  You can download it in Rich Text, or view it in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a RSS feed generator for your Facebook Statuses (or Photos) like the [RSS Feeds](http://apps.facebook.com/rss-feeds/) application on Facebook.
It will help you generate a RSS feed for all your statuses and photos while maintaining the privacy modes.
Although, I am not a fan of the user interface the application has, but the functionality is what is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

connect [facebook to twitter](http://andreavahl.com/facebook/how-do-i-link-facebook-and-twitter.php) and backup with [twitter's backup](http://tweetbackup.com/) tools.